# How to write an advanced laravel elixir gulpfile

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir, gulp-less

I work for the first time with Laravel. I'm used to work with gulp and I usually use a manual method in the gulpfile. I'd want tranform it with laravel-elixir but i'm lost with the following problematics:

- Several files locations and types (css, less).
- I'd like to use the .env (APP_ENV) variable if it's possible
- Use the watcher

Exemple of code:
    // Requires
    var gulp = require('gulp');

```
// Include plugins
var less = require('gulp-less');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');


// Styles LESS
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            'vendor/bower_components/one/less/one.less',
            'vendor/bower_components/two/css/two.css',
            'resources/assets/less/app.less'
        ])
        .pipe(gulpif(/[.]less/, less()))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulpif(elixir.config.production == true, minifycss({keepBreaks:false,keepSpecialComments:0})))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));

});

gulp.task('serve', function() {

    browserSync({
        proxy: {
            target: "local.dev"
        },
        open: false
    });

    gulp.watch(['resources/assets/less/**/*.less'], ['styles']).on('change',     reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

How can I translate this file with Elixir. I've